# Redirect if URL does not match

Tags: 7, .htaccess

I am using D7.

I am attempting to create a redirect in my .htaccess file that will redirect the page **if** the path **doesn't match a pattern**.

```
# only if a particular domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.domain\.org$ [NC]
# only if URI contains "library"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Library$ [NC]
# rewrite the URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://otherdomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine for most of the site (e.g. http://mysite.domain.org/blogs is redirected to http://otherdomain.org/blogs

However, http://mysite.domain.org/Library?id=1234 is being redirected but to http://otherdomain.org?id=1234 ("library" in URI is missing but this shouldn't redirect at all)

What am I missing?  Am I running into Drupal URL rewriting rules?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. Did you write those rules before, or after the ones used by Drupal?

Comment: They come right before the index.php section

Comment: FYI.  I couldn't get this to work but I am not sure if Drupal's own internal functions were interfering.  We abandoned this for a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# only if a particular domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.domain\.org$ [NC]
# rewrite the URL
RewriteRule ^((?!Library).*)$ http://otherdomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The (?!Library) should look ahead, and the match should fail if "Library" is present. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Getting a 500 error.  `RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters`

Comment: Fixed.  I had a space between the flags.

Comment: Its not failing with "library" in the URL. Its still rewriting the URL.

Comment: Library or library? It will be case sensitive.

Comment: I have tried it both ways and with NC flag.  Same results.  The actual URL I am trying to rewrite is "Library".

Comment: oops. It's been too long since my Perl days. Try this instead: **RewriteRule ^((?!Library).)*$ http://otherdomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]**.